# Tortoisesvn ignore file without unversionioning it

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In Tortoisesvn, how can I ignore a file without unversionioning it ?

I mean the file is actually a part of the repository (versioned), but it is just that I have changed it locally (kind of local db settings u can say) and I do not want it to show up in the list everytime I do Commit.

So basically I need to do settings which would impact only my local working.

Answer (score 2):

[Excluding Items from the Commit List](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html#tsvn-dug-commit-ignore)

> Sometimes you have versioned files that change frequently but that you
>   really don't want to commit. Sometimes this indicates a flaw in your
>   build process - why are those files versioned? should you be using
>   template files? But occasionally it is inevitable. A classic reason is
>   that your IDE changes a timestamp in the project file every time you
>   build. The project file has to be versioned as it includes all the
>   build settings, but it doesn't need to be committed just because the
>   timestamp changed.
>
> To help out in awkward cases like this, we have reserved a changelist
>   called ignore-on-commit. Any file added to this changelist will
>   automatically be unchecked in the commit dialog. You can still commit
>   changes, but you have to select it manually in the commit dialog.

Right click on your modified file and click `SVN commit...` to open up commit dialog. Inside commit dialog, `right click your file > Move to change list > ignore-on-commit`.

Now your file will show up unchecked in commit dialog.

Comment: Thanks...so it would still appear in the commit dialog, but unchecked....what happens if I select it & Commit...will the changes be ignored by SVN ?

Comment: If you select and commit, it will not be ignored. As you already know, you can not ignore versioned files, this is just a Tortoise way to help in this kind of situation.